# What is R's implicit vector repetition called?

Tags: r, vector

The following code repeats a vector `c(3,4)` twice to fill a data frame.

```
> data.frame(x=c(1,2,5,6), y=c(3,4))
  x y
1 1 3
2 2 4
3 5 3
4 6 4
```

What is this behavior called exactly, and is there a good reference for how it works?

I'm sure this question has been asked a million times, but I just can't remember the terms, so all my searches for "r vector repetition" and so on go to the wrong place.

Comment: It is known as recycling values!

Comment: See the R language defintion: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Recycling-rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you look for it is known as recycling values. This can be seen  that `data.frame()` function in order to create the rectangular structure with a determined number of rows and columns, it will place values according to the length of the dataframe. For example:

```
#Code 1
df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10,1,1),v2=1)
```

Output:

```
            v1 v2
1   2.54778001  1
2  -0.69632427  1
3   1.51183106  1
4   1.68531980  1
5  -0.70046933  1
6   1.40192042  1
7  -0.09775118  1
8   2.07676738  1
9   1.82864514  1
10  1.82787072  1
```

In this case `v2` will be recycled 1 time because of its length. Now another example:

```
#Code 2
df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10,1,1),v2=1:2)
```

Output:

```
           v1 v2
1   0.4479530  1
2   1.4414374  2
3  -0.6545890  1
4   0.6860653  2
5   0.5052426  1
6   0.8525879  2
7   1.6122026  1
8   0.4432882  2
9   2.1471107  1
10 -0.7284869  2
```

Same logic, the function will recycle values according to the length of the largest vector. Just be careful that recycling is done when the length of vectors are multiples. This is when they have a factor in common. For example, `df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10,1,1),v2=1:3)` will produce error but `df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(9,1,1),v2=1:3)` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `tibble`

```
library(tibble)

tibble(v1=rnorm(10,1,1),v2=1)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#        v1    v2
#     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 -0.524      1
# 2  1.41       1
# 3  0.0863     1
# 4  0.344      1
# 5 -0.0997     1
# 6  0.214      1
# 7 -0.362      1
# 8  2.80       1
# 9  0.707      1
#10  0.955      1
```